# I installed Programmer Dvorak Keyboard Layout and now I have 4 entries in my language preferences in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-layout, dvorak

Normally I type using a Swedish QWERTY layout. Recently I've been learning Dvorak as well. So I added "United States Dvorak" in Windows and it worked fine. If I pressed Win-Space I toggled between the two keyboard layouts.

However, I went and installed [Programmer Dvorak Keyboard Layout](http://www.kaufmann.no/roland/dvorak/). I followed the instructions so I had both "Swedish QWERTY" and "Programmer Dvorak". The problem was that, pressing Win-Space to toggle between them wasn't working anymore.

The instructions on the website states:

> In some builds the layout doesn't appear in the switcher unless the same workaround as for Windows 8 has also been applied.
>
> Windows 8 and 8.1
>   Windows 8 and 8.1 seem to have a problem with custom keyboards; they install fine but are not recognized by the user interface. You can use this work-around to activate Programmer Dvorak:
>
> Follow the official procedure to add "English" as a language and activate "English (United States)" as the default layout.
>
> Run these commands at the Command Prompt:
>
> reg add "HKCU\Keyboard Layout\Substitutes" /v 00000409 /t REG_SZ /d 19360409 /f
>
> reg add "HKCU\Keyboard Layout\Preload" /v 1 /t REG_SZ /d 00000409 /f
>
> Log off and back on again.
>   If you want to have one of the built-in layout enabled too, you should follow the above instructions first, and then add it afterwards.

I followed them, but I instead made it first so I only had "Swedish QWERTY" selected. After restarting, I now have 4 entries in my keyboards:

[image]

I only want one "Swedish Keyboard" and one "Programmer Dvorak Keyboard". But I have no idea how to remove those others ones. If I go to my language settings I see this:

[image]

Under **"English (United Kingdom)"** I see this:

[image]

Under **"English (United States)"** I see this:

[image]

So there seems to only two keyboards installed, but four are showing up. Does anyone have advice on how to get this fixed?

Answer (score 2):

After some experimentation, here's what I did:

1. I was unable to click "Remove" on either keyboard, as you can see in the screenshots
2. I was unable to delete the language "English (United Kingdom)"
3. I selected "English (United Kingdom)" and clicked the Down Arrow to move it to below "English (United States)"
4. I could now select and delete "English (United Kingdom)"
5. I now only had "English (United States)" left and inside of it was only "Programmer Dvorak". I pressed "Add a keyboard" and selected "Swedish QWERTY"
6. The switch keyboard dialogue still showed 4 languages, but in the wrong order
7. Restarted my computer *twice*
8. Success! Now I have only the two keyboard layouts:

[image]

My only problem now is that I want to default to "Swedish Keyboard" instead of "Programmer Dvorak". I do not know how to change the default one. There are no arrows to move them up or down in the language settings. I dare not experiment further :)

*(Note that this reset all my date/time formatting in Windows, but search "Change the date and time" in the settings and you will be able to switch it back)*

Comment: Oddly, my language list arbitrarily seems to expand from my 2 desired ones to the set of 4. 

Nevertheless, I do know when you can set defaults. 
At the bottom of the "Preferred languages" list, there is a link to "Choose an input method to always use as default". The dropdown menu allows you to override the language list.